# Существуют ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для разработки GUI на Java, кроме JavaFX и Swing?

Tags: java, javafx, swing, gui, поиск-библиотек

Изучаю Java относительно недавно и начал задумываться о том, чтобы написать какое-то приложение с GUI. Если хочу в будущем писать desktop apps, стоит ли дальше изучать Java, или же лучше перейти на более подходящий для этого язык? Если да, то на какой лучше перейти?

Comment: Для разработки GUI на Java прекрасно подойдет Java FX.

Comment: Да, существуют. Да, плохо искали. Да, стоит изучать. Какой лучше - миллион мнений.

Comment: Когда не знаешь, что учить, открываешь сайт с вакансиями, находишь самые востребованные и высокооплачиваемые и смотришь, что для них требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Общая идея, как должен выглядеть интерфейс приложения будет диктовать выбор GUI-библиотеки.
Очевидно, что если это интерфейс 3D-шутера, то выбирать между Swing'ом и JavaFx'ом не придется...

Для desktop-приложений с простым GUI в виде окон с полями ввода, кнопочками и без дополнительной анимации, 
на мой взгляд, наиболее продуктивно будет начать со Swing.

Swing - это довольно простая по возможностям библиотека, которая позволит реализовывать разнообразные 
расчетные и тестовые программки "для себя", а также интрефейсы к базам данных (в принципе то, 
для чего обычно используется WindowsForms).

Swing очень хорошо документирован. Исходный код библиотеки выверен годами и там много где "постелено соломки".
К тому же практически на любой нюанс можно найти уже готовый ответ даже в пределах сайта stackoverflow.com.

При использовании визуальных редакторов (встроенных в IDE или платного JFormDesigner) разработка довольно быстрая 
и простая.

Для изучения Swing порекомендую книгу Ивана Портянкина "Java Swing: Эффектные пользовательские интерфейсы" (2-е издание второе, 2011)
(pdf/epub и ссылка на github с примерами есть на сайте автора http://www.ipsoftware.ru ).

Когда же Вам захочется особой красоты в интерфейсе, то уже будет множество альтернатив:
делать ли свой Look-and-Feel для Swing или просто вставить Swing-контрол в JavaFx-приложение, а может
переписать все на JavaFx (к тому же станет понятнее его статус после того, как его "изгнали" из JRE/JDK, 
да и документации и ответов по JavaFx должно прибавиться); или вообще отказаться от Java для GUI.

PS: Возможно, немногие, кто знаком со Swing'ом видели 
[канал пользователя KeepToo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nEluKUOic8), в котором
показано, как, практически с помощью одних только JPanel, можно создавать довольно свежие интерфейсы вроде такого:

[image: Java Netbeans Swing UI Design - UI 2017]

Там также есть аналогичные примеры для JavaFx.

Comment: JavaFX не изгнали, а вынесли в отдельный модуль. Это плановые работы по модуляризации стандартной библиотеки и весьма вероятно, что Swing тоже вынесут в одной из будущих версий.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev потому и в кавычках )